# Bounding the error in a solution, to an IVP, produced by RK4.

Tags: numerical-methods, runge-kutta-methods, truncation-error

What techniques exist for bounding the error in a solution, to an IVP, produced by RK4? The below problem is intended to contextualize the question.

**Problem**

The $x$, $y$ and $z$ axes of a coordiante system point to (are positive in the direction of) east, north and up, respectively. A man standing at the origin of this coordinate system throws a ball with an initial velocity of 25 m/s from a height of 1.4 m. The throw is made at a 30° angle in the -plane (vertical plane) and a 0° angle in the -plane (horizontal plane). In other words, the ball is thrown at a 30° angle (in the vertical plane) along the positive $x$-axis.

The differential equations describing the ball's trajectory are

$$
\ddot{x}=-q \dot{x}, \: \ddot{y}=-q(\dot{y}-a(z)), \: \ddot{z}=-9.81-q \dot{z}, \: \text {where} \: q=c \sqrt{\dot{x}^{2}+(\dot{y}-a(z))^{2}+\dot{z}^{2}}.
$$

The air resistance coefficient $c$ is a function of the ball's radius and mass. For the ball in this problem, $c = 0.070$. The wind speed is 7 m/s on the ground, and increases with height according to $a(z) = 7 + 0.35z$.

Given the above conditions, I want to compute the ball's point of impact with an accuracy of at least $\pm10^{-4}$ m for each coordinate.

**Soltuion**

The above differential equations can be solved numerically by using an ODE solver such as Euler's method or RK4. I have solved them using RK4. However, to apply RK4, the equations need to be rewritten as a first-order system. This is done below.

\begin{eqnarray}
   s_1 = x \quad s_3 = y \quad s_5 = z \\
   s_2 = \dot{x} \quad s_4 = \dot{y} \quad s_6 = \dot{z}
\end{eqnarray}

\begin{equation}
    \begin{bmatrix}
        \dot{s_1} \\
        \dot{s_2} \\
        \dot{s_3} \\
        \dot{s_4} \\
        \dot{s_5} \\
        \dot{s_6}
    \end{bmatrix} =
    \begin{bmatrix}
        s_2 \\
        -qs_2 \\
        s_4 \\
        -q(s_4 - a(s_5)) \\
        s_6 \\
        -9.810 - qs_6 \\
    \end{bmatrix}.
\end{equation}

Now, by choosing

\begin{equation}
   \mathbf{s}_0 =
   \begin{bmatrix}
      0 \\
      25\cos \pi/6 \\
      0 \\
      0 \\
      1.4 \\
      25\sin \pi/6
   \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
as the starting condition and setting the step-size to $h = 0.00001$ s, the RK4 solver returns the solution
$$(x, y, z) = (18.122755453098357, \: 9.016849403591824, \: -1.7008908075912395 \times 10^{-5}).$$

**Question**

What techniques can be used to bound the error in the computed point of impact?

Comment: Your step size is probably too small. With standard double precision, $Lh=10^{-3}$ is optimal for RK4, where $L$ is a local Lipschitz constant around the solution path. // Compute the same solution with different step sizes and use Richardson extrapolation to compute an error estimate. Or just compute the results $r_k$ using $h_k=2^k\cdot 10^{-4}$ and tabulate/plot $(r_{k}-r_{k-1})/h_k^4$. You should get a constant $C$ over some range of step sizes, $Ch^4$ is then a good error estimate.

Comment: @LutzL Could you provide an example of how to use Richardson extrapolation to compute an error estimate?